# Use non-debug python.dll from debug C API

Tags: python

I am calling the Python C API. I compile the C code as debug (specifically, the Debug configuration in Visual Studio), but I want the Python runtime to *not* be in debug mode. Specifically, I want it to continue to load python.dll, not python_d.dll (which tries to load the debug version of the precompiled packages which I don't have).

How can I compile my C project as debug, but use the non-debug version of the Python runtime? Do I have to undefine some DEBUG definition before include Python.h?

Comment: It's been a long time since I encountered exactly this issue, but the short answer is you can't do it.

Comment: I tried to temporarily undefine _DEBUG when I include Python.h as follows:

    #undef _DEBUG
    #include <Python.h>
    #define _DEBUG 1

This works for me. Should I anticipate any problems with this solution?

Comment: Like I said it's been a long time, but as I recall the issue is due to the Python interpreter using one version of the C runtime and the extension using another (and the two don't mix). Apparently there are/were some `#pragma` directives in the Python interpreter's source code that control which C runtime dll it uses at runtime. It's possible, of course, that things have changed...but if what you're doing seems to work, why are you even asking this question? I think the solution is to build your own debugging version of the Python interpreter (which requires obtaining all of its source code).